# React Native & Meteor implementation

Tags: ios, meteor, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react native app with a meteor backend. I know to tie these two together I have to use the node package ddp-client for the app to connect. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp-client

But what is the best practice for going about this. Should I:

1. Define the DDPClient and connect in index.ios.js where i keep connected and find some way to issue requests from the main app component? (I wouldnt know how to do this however but it would be a start.)
2. Only connect through dpp on each component that I need this for and issue a request each time?

Really any real example would help. Most of the code I find online are single page examples with not much else. Or just a push in the right direction.

p.s. The app is a marketplace. Thanks!

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  NavigatorIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBarIOS,
} = React;

var DDPClient = require("ddp-client");

class AppWrapper extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    var ddpClient = new DDPClient({url: 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket'});

    ddpClient.connect(function(error, wasReconnect) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('DDP connection error!');
        return;
      }
      if (wasReconnect) {
         console.log('Reestablishment of a connection.');
       }
      console.log('connected!');
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <NavigatorIOS
        barTintColor='black'
        titleTextColor='white'
        tintColor='white'
        style={styles.container}
        translucent={false}
        initialRoute={{
          backButtonTitle: ' ',
          component: Homeios,
          title: 'hombro',
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('someApp', () => AppWrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-meteor package in your react native app which is pretty easy. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor check this link for documentation it has many awesome functions including Accounts package ready to use.